# How can I set dynamic height of image using react-native-fast-image?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-fast-image

I want to change height based on height of each image.

```
  <FastImage
              style={{
                width: Width,
                height: this.state.imageHeight
              }}
              source={{
                uri: `${imageAPI}/${item}`
              }}
              resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
              onLoad={evt =>
                this.setState({
                  originWidth: evt.nativeEvent.width,
                  originHeight: evt.nativeEvent.height,
                  imageHeight:
                    (evt.nativeEvent.height / evt.nativeEvent.width) * Width // By this, you keep the image ratio
                })
              }
            />
```

On onLoad props, I was trying to get height of image and manage that in state. There's no problem with this. I'm getting height of image well.

But the height of image are not changed.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @gwanhui-kim, did you solve this ?